# Adding class to dynamically created component angular

Tags: angular, dynamic

i have the following code,

```
createComponent(message, some_css_class) {
    this.msg.reset();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MessageComponent);
    const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
    componentRef.instance.message = message;
    //how to add the passed css class to the this component
}
```

here i dynamically create the component, now need to add the passed css class to it.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular 5/6, using Renderer2 from @angular/core, you can try like below,

```
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private renderer2: Renderer2) { }

createComponent(message, some_css_class) {
    this.msg.reset();
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MessageComponent);
    const componentRef = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
    componentRef.instance.message = message;
    this.renderer2.addClass(componentRef.location.nativeElement, some_css_class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `componentRef.instance.cssClass = some_css_class` and `@HostBinding('class') public cssClass;` inside of a component